# Error message "deduced conflicting types for parameter 'const T'"

Tags: c++, c++11

What I'm trying to do:

> Write a specialized version of the template from the previous exercise to handle `vector<const char*>` and a program that
>   uses this specialization.

I wrote the program like this:

```
template<typename T>
int count(vector<T> tvec, const T &t);

template<>
int count(vector<const char *> tvec, const char *const &s)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (auto c : tvec)
        if (c == s) {
            ++count;
        }
    return count;
}

template<typename T>
int count(vector<T> tvec, const T &t)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (auto c : tvec)
        if (c == t) {
            ++count;
        }
    return count;
}

cout << count(svec, "GUO");
```

but I get the error that says

`deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘const T’ (‘std::basic_string<char>’ and ‘char [4]’)`

I want to know how to handle this. and further, in the template function, it seems that an array can be changed to the pointer, why my program cannot handle it?

Comment: Btw. comparing raw strings by operator == will only compare pointers. Use `strcmp()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't deduce on both parameters, it leads to conflicts. Write this:

```
template <typename T>
int count(const vector<T>& tvec, const typename vector<T>::value_type& t);
```

Also, consider overloading instead of specializing. Specializing a function template is pretty much never what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it seems `svec` is defined as `vector<string>`, maybe it should be `vector<const char*>`;

Secondly, explictly define a var as const char*;

Try this:

```
vector<const char*> svec;
const char* chars = "GUO";
std::cout<<my_count(svec,chars);
```

BTW: A variable of type char array(char[]) can be used as type char pointer(char*), but they are different as type, and they are different as a template paremeter.

Comment: Thanks, but if I want to use the literal string as the second argument, how should I implement the specialized template?

Comment: @user3335905 You can define svec like `vector<char[4]> svec;`, and the main template function will be called. So may be you need to define a specialized template for `char[]`. Char array is not same as char pointer as data type.

Comment: `vector<char[4]> svec;` is not actually possible since C-Array is not copyable/moveable/assignable.

Comment: An alternative is `my_count<const char*>(svec, "GUO")`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, you are right. I'm just not sure what is the result he wanted because the `operator==` for the element of svec is meaningless.