# Deduced conflicting types for universal reference and pointer to member

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, forwarding-reference

I want a function like this:

```
template<typename C, typename T>
void foo(C &&aclass, T (C::*const memberFunc)(unsigned)) {

}
```

The parameters are (in words because C/C++ type syntax is mental):

- A universal reference to a class, e.g. `MyClass`.
- A const pointer to a member function of `MyClass` that takes an unsigned int and returns `T`.

This sort of works, however if I call it with an l-value reference as the first parameter I get an error like:

> candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'C' ('MyClass &' vs. 'MyClass')

As far as I understand it, it is deducing `C` from the first and second parameters, but comes up with different deductions and gets confused.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21933915/265521) you can make it only do deduction on the first parameter, and somehow use the `typename` keyword on the second parameter. But I can't work out the syntax to do this when I do want it to deduce one of the types in the parameter (`T`), but not the other (`C`).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24622058/265521) is also helpful but they solve it by just not using references for `C` at all, which *in that case* is equally efficient, but not in mine.

Is this possible?

Comment: I daresay that holding C accountable for a syntax it doesn't have is unfair

Comment: I meant the syntax used to specify types in C is bonkers. The result is often worse in C++ because its types are more complex, but [the complicated syntax comes from C](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With lvalues `C` will be deduced to be an lvalue-reference type (i.e. `MyClass &` for your case) for the 1st parameter, which is the expected behavior of [forwarding reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references); you can remove the reference-ness via [std::remove_reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) when using `C` in the 2nd parameter, e.g.

```
template<typename C, typename T>
void foo(C &&aclass, T (std::remove_reference_t<C>::*const memberFunc)(unsigned)) {

}
```

And as @Quentin pointed, using of `std::remove_reference` also introduces [non-deduced context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts), that would prevent `C` from being deduced from the 2nd parameter.

Comment: It's worth noting that `std::remove_reference` will *also* introduce a non-deduced context, which is helpful.

Comment: Did you mean to have `_t` on the end of `remove_reference`?

Comment: @Timmmm Yes. This feature was introduced from C++14; in C++11 you can write `typename std::remove_reference<C>::type` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just found that having a universal reference overload forward it to an l-value reference version works. Not particularly elegant though; I feel like there should be a better way.

```
template<typename C, typename T>
void foo(C &aclass, T (C::*const memberFunc)(unsigned)) {
  // Code goes here.
}

template<typename C, typename T>
void foo(C &&aclass, T (C::*const memberFunc)(unsigned)) {
  foo(aclass, memberFunc);
}
```